# Problem in using both CocoaPods and Swift Package Manager

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I'm using CocoaPod and SPM in the same iOS project

**Problem is**

```
Library A: in CocoaPod
    have a dependency on RxSwift
Library B: in SPM
    have a dependency on RxSwift
```

When I build with library AB, **runtime error** created like below.
How can I solve this problem? (help..!)

```
objc[17036]: Class
_TtC7RxSwiftP33_AB3B9E8806A71B46FB498A7594F5E0D919AnonymousDisposable is implemented
in both /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D98DDCF9-AC7B-4D37-921A-
F4BC5F852576/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BBDC1A45-0526-4B27-AC8B-
2F029129BB30/{AppName}/Frameworks/RxSwift.framework/RxSwift (0x11ad0d938) 

and 
/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D98DDCF9-AC7B-4D37-921A-
F4BC5F852576/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BBDC1A45-0526-4B27-AC8B-
2F029129BB30/{AppName}.app/{AppName} (0x107748c78). One of the two will be used. 
Which one is undefined.
    
enter failed to demangle superclass of FlatMapSink from mangled name 'MW��yxq_q0_G': 
subject type q0_ does not conform to protocol ObserverType
```

Comment: SPM and CocoaPods do not support interoperability.